# Using open source apps source code under Apache v2

Tags: licensing, git, android, github, apache-license

I modified some code and added few (minor) changes to an open source Android app. Now I want to publish it on play store. The app is licensed under Apache license v2. The license file is included in the project but there is no name of the author on it. It is just an Apache terms and conditions file nothing else.

There is no copyright note anywhere in the project. What should I do? Should I publish it without the license? I can get the name of the author by visiting his profile (the project is on GitHub). Should I add a copyright notice in code?

Comment: Voting to close as this is rather a question for a lawyer.

Comment: Have you read the Apache license to learn it's terms and conditions, and find out what it says you are allowed to do and not allowed to do?

Comment: [Are there any impediment in the Apache License 2.0 to sell software?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/279551/are-there-any-impediment-in-the-apache-license-2-0-to-sell-software)

Comment: I removed the legal aspects of the question as they are off topic for this site.  Questions about software licenses however are on topic if asking for the perspective of a developer and not a lawyer.

Comment: The answer below pretty much states that you must include the original license.  It also states that if you modify source you must state so in some form in your distributed project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read and understand the entire [license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

Here are a few noteworthy points:

> 1. Grant of Copyright License. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, each Contributor hereby grants to You a perpetual... ...no-charge,...  ...copyright license to reproduce, prepare Derivative Works... ...and distribute the... ...Derivative Works in Source or Object form.
> 2. Redistribution. You may reproduce and distribute copies of the Work or Derivative Works thereof in any medium, with or without modifications, and in Source or Object form, provided that You meet the following conditions:
>
>    - You must [include...] a copy of this License; and
>    - You must cause any modified files to carry prominent notices stating that You changed the files

So the quick answer is that you may redistribute the software, with or without modification, provided that you continue to do so under the same license, following its terms. This is a common condition of many open source licences. But again, you must read the license itself for its actual terms and conditions.

For a legal opinion of a particular situation, or possible legal ramifications, you should consult a lawyer knowledgeable in intellectual property law.